# Write in webserver logs with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, logging, webserver

I've a small problem: with my AngularJS application the logs of web server are written when the page is loaded at the first time, but with `ui-router` the page won't be loaded next time so the web server will never write to my `access_log`.

I would like to know if exists some solution.

I want to be able to log at least the url navigating.

Thanks,
Davide

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you. [Logging client side errors](http://engineering.talis.com/articles/client-side-error-logging/)

Comment: This is similar? https://github.com/csnover/TraceKit , are you sure that stacktrace.js logging in server side from angularjs?